# Вывод информации из таблицы mysql

Tags: mysql, python

Использую библиотеку mysqldb

```
import MySQLdb
con = MySQLdb.connect(host="host", user="uzer", passwd="1111", db="bazadann")
con.close()
```

Как вывести всю информацию из таблицы "test"

```
     for row in cur.fetchall()
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: берете делайте запрос а базу данных `con.execute("select * from test"); a = con.fetchall(); print(a)`. А вообще это все в [документции описано](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html)

Comment: File "bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    a = con.fetchall()
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'fetchall'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
import MySQLdb

con = MySQLdb.connect(host="host", user="uzer", passwd="1111", db="bazadann")

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM test")

for row in cur.fetchall():
    print(row)

con.close()
```

[Здесь](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm) можно найти больше примеров по работе с БД в Python

---

Модуль [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) позволяет значительно упростить код и выводить данные в табличном виде:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

db_connection = 'mysql+pymysql://mysql_user:mysql_password@localhost/db_name'
conn = create_engine(db_connection)

df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM test", conn)
print(df)
```

Comment: File "bot.py", line 3
    cur = con.cursor()
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @0x00, можете привести в вопросе полный текст `error traceback`?

Comment: Привёл, смотрите.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @0x00, да, двоеточия не хватало - уже исправил в ответе...

Comment: Можете подсказать, можно ли это как-нибудь в красивый вид привести?